# using terra to plot a netcdf returning an error

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, terra

I've downloaded and import a Level 3 netcdf file for the OMI instrument. You can download a sample here:
https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/login?code=nY1ztQoDBlvAgq4cM19h-uxNn54_nx7l0wtOgykcznvRxbtvxyHDlJrGZkF1nRFufubxyNwsOmq6jcURkTWn&state=%2Fdata%2FMINDS%2FOMI_MINDS_NO2d.1.1%2F2016%2FOMI-Aura_L3-OMI_MINDS_NO2d_2016m0105_v01-01-2022m0218t115317.nc

I'm using the terra package to import it as follows:

```
path = "OMI-Aura_L3-OMI_MINDS_NO2d_2016m0101_v01-01-2022m0218t115312.nc"


r1 <- terra::rast(path,subds = "ColumnAmountNO2") ## select the variable name

plot(r1)
```

It's returning the following error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : 
  invalid type passed to graphics function
```

But the output of r1 looks good:

```
> r1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25723 +no_defs 
source      : OMI-Aura_L3-OMI_MINDS_NO2d_2016m0101_v01-01-2022m0218t115312.nc:ColumnAmountNO2 
varname     : ColumnAmountNO2 (NO2 Vertical Column Density) 
name        : ColumnAmountNO2_Time=16071.5 
unit        :                    molec/cm2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `terra::plot(r1)` or load `library(terra)` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Grzegorz Sapijaszko you need to explicitly use `terra::plot` or use `library(terra)`

Problem:

```
x <- terra::rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1:100)
plot(x)
#Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : 
#  invalid type passed to graphics function
```

Solution:

```
terra::plot(x)
```

Or

```
library(terra)
plot(x)
```

Comment: I did that and it worked, but it returns a warning: Warning message:
In .get_breaks(z, length(out$cols), "eqint", out$range) :
  probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus